# Grails: how to set language dynamically in gsp or using js

Tags: grails, gsp

I want to set language value of a gsp page dynamically .  Currently I am just doing it using basic hardcoded value . I did find something with JS Onload event described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187645/backbone-how-to-set-html-lang-attribute-dynamically).

But I wanted to find something that is GSP driven . Is there any way ?

My current code looks like  `<html lang="en">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe you are thinking of this in a more complex way than it actuall is.

In grails you have your layouts/main.gsp which is your sitemesh.

The tag `<html lang='en'` is declared at the very top of this

If you simply edit this page and add the following:

```
<g:set var="locale" value="${session?.'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE'?:java.util.Locale.UK}"/>
<html lang="${locale?.language?:'en'}" class="no-js">
```

Then when I visit my site:
`localhost:8080/?lang=ja_JP`  view source shows:
`<html lang="ja" class="no-js">`

You need to do that for each sitemesh that requires to do this - having a read about this property it seems it doesn't do much for the browser but may help non human things such as search engines.

Comment: cool, ye sorry wasn't sure after answering if this was a deeper question lurking in the Javascript world due to the angle, anyhow hope you are through the hurdle :)

Comment: Yeah just wanted something like this .. I did not want to use JS to modify the tag and add attribute .. Thanks