# How can I save the language of the login page and will be displayed in the next page using JavaScript and without localstorge?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, get, set

How can you save the last language displayed in the login page and going to the next page and garding the same language for exemple i choose French in the login page and the next page must be in french.

I've used this code :

```
<!--Login.html-->
<script>
    function saveAndRedirect() {
        // Get the selected language from the dropdown
        var selectedLanguage = document.getElementById("languageSelect").value;

        // Redirect to the next page with the selected language as a query parameter
        window.location.href = "home.html?lang=" + selectedLanguage;
    }
</script>
 
<!--home.html-->

<script>

    // Retrieve the language from the query parameter in the URL
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var userLanguage = urlParams.get('lang');

    // Example: Set the document language
    document.documentElement.lang = userLanguage;

</script>
```

Comment: Odd requirement to not use localStorage, as it's the ideal solution. Are you able to sue Cookies? That would be the easiest client-side alternative. Also, is there a specific reason you're using a language dropdown instead of reading the `accept-language` header in the request to set the preferred language the user has specifically chosen in their browser? Doing that would make this issue completely moot

Comment: If you have a login, then I would assume you have some sort of server-side - you could store the language against the user's profile

Comment: What doesn't work with your current solution?   What's the value of `userLanguage` when you debug it?   There are existing questions on SO that appear to use the same code for setting documentElement.lang, eg [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187645/how-to-set-html-lang-attribute-dynamically) - so maybe it's an issue with how you use `document.documentElement.lang`?  Or maybe your first page's `select` doesn't have compatible values?